# Change button function during animation

Tags: java, android, animation, button, android-studio

I need to change button function during animation playback
@JulianoNunesSilvaOliveria said that I can  change it by flag variable :

```
boolean something = false; if (something) { doA(); something = false;} else { doB(); }
```

but how i  use it?
i start animation like this

```
oilcan.startAnimation(seq1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AnimatorListener:

```
oilcan.animate().setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                  something = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                  something = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
        }
```